# jQuery addClass or wrap in unlikely part of element

Tags: jquery, addclass

I really hate the way my shopping cart is set up as I CANNOT edit much of the pages.  So I resort to using jQuery which is both fun and frustrating because we have to use so much of it.  That being said..I am trying to find a way through jQuery to add a class specifically for the price given two situations.  Unfortunately the price is not set up to add a class to it specifically (why my shopping cart did it this way is beyond me!).  Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Perhaps I need to use `wrap()` method to wrap the price and give it a class?

```
<-- Situation 1 -->
<b>
  <font class="text colors_text">
  <b>Regular Price: </b>
  </font>
   $2,533.31
</b> 

<-- Situation 2 -->
<b>
  <span class="exclusive">Exclusive Price:</span>
  <font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">$2,343.30</font>
</b>
```

I'm not going to dwell into the reasons why I need to add a class to these prices because there is a lot riding behind the class name which enables much of the page to render correctly.  The class names for each situation should be the SAME. Situation 2 I may be able to handle with ease `$('.exclusive').next('font').addClass('priceis')` but Situation 1 is pretty tough.

Comment: Are you saying (for situation 1) that you want to add the class priceis to the <b> tag? If not which tag? Or do you need to add a tag around the literal price?

Comment: In Situation 2 you have an extraneous floating `</span>`...

Comment: @David Thomas Yeah I noticed I copied it in wrong.

Comment: @Sam Huggill I just want to add the class 'priceis' to the PRICE itself nothing else.

Comment: OK I suggest updating your question to clarify this - as some answers are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For situation one you could do:

```
var font = $(".text");//get the font tag
$(font.get(0).nextSibling).wrap('<span class="priceis" />'); 
//wrap it's next sibling inside a span
```

this add a span around the price with the desired class

Comment: Thanks everyone this did the trick for me.  I actually needed it on the 2nd instance of .text so I added `$('.text:eq(1)')`

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this

Answer (score 1):

```
// get first "b" element
var b = $("b:eq(0)");

// get font element
var font = b.find("font:eq(0)");

// clone font element
var fontClone = font.clone();

// remove font element
font.remove();

// get remaining text (the price)
var price = b.html();

// replace "b" tag's html with span with class "priceis" containing price
b.html("<span class=\"priceis\">" + price + "</span>");

// put the font clone back in
b.preprend(fontClone);
```

Comment: That was for "situation 1" by the way.

Comment: I think you can make it simpler! :)